# Run cmd in background in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

How do i run a cmd in background and return to next line in shell script 
test.sh ->

```
bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bashrc; ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=connectionstring && exit')
mysql -u root -p --host 127.0.0.1
```

The first cmd gives the output as

```
2018/01/05 01:49:28 Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for connectionstring
2018/01/05 01:49:28 Ready for new connections
```

so 2 cmd is never executed.

Basically I want to run 1 cmd in background, so that 2 cmd is executed.

Comment: `man bash` and search for background? Search here for `[bash] background`? Good luck.

Comment: Got it doing this way

Answer (score 0):

I got the way to fix the issue

```
cmd="./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=connectionstring"
echo "starting service"
$cmd </dev/null >proxy.out 2>proxy.err &
mysql -u root -p --host 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Appending '&' to the end of the line will run it in background.

eg..
$ ls -l &

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.